# How to make a part of Chrome "always on top"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromium

Edit on 20190109. Just to clarify some thinks.
1. This is quite an old question, closed and yes off-topic (and also kind of a xy-problem question), still if you feel like it go on and down-vote it, I couldn't care less.
2. When I posted the question I wasn't aware of Electron and the solution it provides to my original requirement (and not the work around I am asking on this question).

---

I was wondering if i could change some things in my chrome with an extension, so when i press..
1) the windows button + D
2) or the minimize button
3) or the "Show Desktop" button in windows 7

..a part of chrome would still be visible, to be more specific i want to turn to a state of "always on top" the 1) tab bar
2) the address bar
3) and the bookmark bar

so is it possible to "split" an application like chrome in two "pieces" and somehow change its visibility in one of those "pieces"? any ideas are welcomed!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to achieve this, in my thought, is combine a third-party program with a chrome extension.

For example, if you are under windows, you can use a program like **[Window On Top](http://www.skybn.com/window-always-on-top/)** by [Skybn](http://www.skybn.com/). This program uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> hotkey to toggle always on top window state, then you make an extension wich manipulate the browser window position and dimensions using the same hotkey.

To get the chrome window on top of screen with only tabs, adress and boookmarks, you can use something like this:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window){
    chrome.windows.update(window.id,{top:0,left:0,width:screen.width,height:100})
});
```

Comment: .. Third part  is?

Comment: @Pacerier I meant a "third-party program", an auxiliary program that isn't either your extension or a Google Chrome feature.